# MapControl using XAML Island in WPF: default map layer is shown over custom tile layer

Tags: wpf, xaml, xaml-islands

I've added a `MapControl` using [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/mapcontrol) to my WPF application. I wanted to add custom map layer to it, so I've added a `OpenStreetMap` tile layer using [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images). I want to remove the default map at all, but it doesn't work.

I've tested the original `MapControl` in a UWP app and it works.

My code in WPF:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <controls:MapControl x:Name="mapControl" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            HttpMapTileDataSource dataSource = new HttpMapTileDataSource("http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{zoomlevel}/{x}/{y}.png");

            MapTileSource tileSource = new MapTileSource(dataSource);
            tileSource.Visible = true;
            tileSource.Layer = MapTileLayer.BackgroundReplacement;
            tileSource.IsFadingEnabled = false;
            mapControl.Style = Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.MapStyle.None;
            mapControl.TileSources.Add(tileSource);
        }
    }
```

This is the WPF application. It shows `OpenStreetMap` layer and also default `Bing` map layer on top:

[image: MapControl in WPF]

This is the UWP app and shows only `OpenStreetMap` perfectly:

[image: MapControl in UWP]

Is there any solution to fix it in WPF?

**Update**

I find out that this line doesn't apply correctly and it caused the error:

```cs
mapControl.Style = Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.MapStyle.None;
```

Comment: Have you considered using an [open-source alternative](https://github.com/ClemensFischer/XAML-Map-Control)?

Comment: @Clemens Yes. I used it. but I have some performance limits and the `Xaml.MapControl` have higher `CPU` usage rather than UWP MapControl. (up to 20%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Add these lines to the initialization code:

```cs
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl originalMapControl =
    mapControl.GetUwpInternalObject() as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl;

if (originalMapControl != null)
{
    originalMapControl.Style = MapStyle.None;
}
```

It fixes the defect.